# How to start up and shut down Windows 2000 Server automatically?

Tags: windows, startup, boot, shutdown

What I am looking for is away for my server to start up and shut down, at the start and end of the business day. I thought I could use task management but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

As you said to shut down the server you can use task manager.

Just create new task:

In the "RUN" field enter:

```
E:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -s -t 60
```

In the "Start in" field enter:

```
E:\WINDOWS\system32
```

Then in the Schedule tab set Scheduled Task and Start time.

But to start up your you can't you Task Manager.

One of the solution:

This can be done by UPS with the Wake-On-LAN function. Wake-on-Lan allows a computer to be turned on or woken up by a network message. More about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN